# When I open a terminal session it shows ~$, how can I solve it?

Tags: command-line

When the terminal is open (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) it shows `username@name: ~$`. Is there any problem with my permissions? It was `/$` before, but I don't know why it changed.

Comment: there is no problem, for me the terminal has always been ~$. But you can change it if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` is the root folder of your installation, and `~` is shell shorthand for `$HOME`, the home directory of the current user. If the terminal started up in `/`, that means you had **non-standard configuration** (at least for Ubuntu) - the `$HOME` directory was missing, the terminal or shell was configured to use `/` as the startup directory, or `PS1` contained something other than the standard. In retrospect it will probably be impossible to pin down exactly what the configuration was, but **don't worry - it's not a problem**.

Answer (score 2):

~ (a home folder) has always been the default one. If it had been different to you, that means your home folder did contain overriding config file.
If you really want to start with another folder, open `Edit - Profile - Edit`,  and there, in `Custom command` field enter `bash /` for example.